# NSFetchedResultsController loads the whole data and bad performance

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a large database with over 8000 entries in it. I want to load and list in `tableview`. I used `NSFetchedResultsController`. It's working fine except the bad performance. I found the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

And added my `performFetch:` method in the `viewDidLoad:` method. But it takes 2-3 seconds to load the view.

Here it is my code.

```
- (void)loadFetchResultsController {
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Error occurs while fetching the foods with fetch results controller %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (isSearching)
    {
        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"SearchResults"];
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *hiddenPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    if (isSearching)
    {
        hiddenPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(hidden == %@) AND (name contains[cd] %@ OR foodDescription contains[cd] %@)",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], searchTerm,searchTerm];
    }
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:hiddenPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name.stringGroupByFirstInitial" cacheName:(isSearching) ? @"SearchResults" : @"Root"];
    _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I used the instruments and found out that calling performFetch: method loads the whole data for the first time when `viewDidLoad:` calls.

[image]

My `food` data model is like this:

[image]

Any idea to improve the performance and get rid of delay.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem occur only with a search predicate or generally?

Comment: It occurs generally.. That search predicate only will work, when search bar search happens.

Comment: @MartinR Any idea about why it is happening?? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I know that case-insensitive queries (such as "name contains[cd]") can be slow, but that would only apply if you have a search expression. Apart from that, I currently do not see a problem in your code.

Comment: Are the hidden and name attributes indexed in your model?

Comment: You can store additional "normalized" attributes which contain the strings converted to lower-case. If you convert the search string also to lower-case then you can compare sensitive, which is much faster.

Comment: In your model, click on the attribute and check the definition to see if it is indexed.  If not, then change it to indexed. This will make your non-search queries much faster.

Comment: It's the `sectionNameKeyPath` argument. Core Data has to fetch everything the first time to build the section indexes.

Comment: @TomHarrington I set the nil for sectionNameKeyPath and tried. But it is still the same issue. Am I missing anything else. I get rid of all the codes related to sections. No improvement.

Comment: contains[cd] is slow if try to search into one - to - many property

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the fetch limit on your fetch request, not just the batch size.  Try calling [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:20]; and see if that helps.  This should cause the first 20 records to be fetched.  Then as the user scrolls through your data, make additional fetch requests to get more data.

Comment: Fetch limit is a limit for a whole fetch request. It will not act like a batch size. If I set a limit as you said, I will get only 20 items and I won't get anything when user scrolls. I already tried it too.